# When do we go for tree data structure?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have seen many famous problems with solutions using tree data structure. But I still don't have a clear understanding on when do programmers go for tree data structure?

Comment: For faster data retrieval. I assume you mean B Tree or BST right?

Comment: I mean the superset of all kind of tree data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used decision trees for my artificial intelligence projects. Training on a decision tree is pretty slow but once it's trained it's faster than a neural network. Of course, they have their advantages and disadvantages, but for my purposes I didn't care that much about how fast it is to train the learner.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But you can also use Candidate elimination to do the same. I want to know is there any specific reason to go for tree based approach.